# How can we add collections in mongoDB dynamically( through users)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

Adding collections manually is easy but adding it dynamically giving me unexpected answer.

I am getting a collection name from frontend to backend using promt and axios but when I am doing

const variable_from_frontEnd = mongoose.model(variable_from_frontEnd, Schema);

it is not adding any collections.

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Messages from "./messages.js";
import cors from "cors";

// app configuration

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

const pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: "1183689",
    key: "c9fa659fc6b359a23989",
    secret: "9da56a5db535e10c7d95",
    cluster: "eu",
    useTLS: true
});

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// DB Configuration

const url = "mongodb+srv://suraj_bisht_99:zoe6B82AZjaLXgw7@cluster0.zp9dc.mongodb.net/Whatsapp_MERN?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(url, {useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .then(()=> console.log('mongoDB is connected'))
        .then(err => console.log(err));


const groupSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    message: String,
    name: String,
    timestamp: String,
    received: Boolean,
});

// API routes

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello World");
})


app.get("/messages/sync", async (req, res) => {
        await Messages.find( (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }else{
                res.status(200).send(data);
            }
        })
})

app.post("/messages/new", async (req, res) => {
     
    try{
        const newMessage = new personalGroup(req.body);
        const newMessageCreated = await newMessage.save();
        res.status(201).send(newMessageCreated);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});

// route for creating new collection in mongoDB
app.post("/room/new", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        let groupName = req.body.room;
        groupName = mongoose.model(groupName, groupSchema);
        
        if(!groupName){
             console.log("error is occured");
        }else{
             console.log(groupName);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
})

// listening part 

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port number ${port}`));
```

Let's say I have type a collection name "studyGroup" from frontend then
console is giving me
Model { studyGroup }

Can someone help me why it is happening and how can I add collections manually.

Comment: I hope `suraj_bisht_99:zoe6B82AZjaLXgw7` are not your real credentials!

Comment: No, it  is right credentials because, if I add collections manually by going to mongodb.com then it is adding but adding it by user is not going to add. Also, if my credentials were wrong then my connection would be break but it is not so.